# XCUiTests App Hierarchy is all Other Elements

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

```
    t =    72.34s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 84589
    t =    72.36s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 84589
▿ Optional<XCUIApplication>
  - some : Attributes: Application, pid: 84589, label: 'MyApp'
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x600001ffa300, pid: 84589, label: 'MyApp'
    Window (Main), 0x600001ffa3e0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
      Other, 0x600001ffa4c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
        Other, 0x600001ffa5a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
      Other, 0x600001ffa680, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
        Other, 0x600001ffa760, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
          Other, 0x600001ffa840, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
            Other, 0x600001ffa920, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
              Other, 0x600001ffaa00, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}, identifier: 'tabBarControllerView'
Path to element:
 →Application, 0x600001ffa300, pid: 84589, label: 'MyApp'
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application '...'
  Output: {
    Application, pid: 84589, label: 'MyApp'
  }
```

My view hierarchy is entirely made of Other Elements when it should be NavigationControllers and TabBarControllers. Any idea why this is?

If it's helpful. We're using the Coordinator pattern to present ViewControllers.

Comment: That’d be a good question for your developers. Mine recently extended a bunch of standard controls and they now come back as “other” type. That may just be how it goes if you’re not using the absolute standard out of the box control.